# Error Restoring GCE From Veeam Backup and Replication

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, restore, disaster-recovery, veeam

i have a project DRC that migrate from onprem VMWare to GCP with Veeam Backup.
the error :
9/21/2023 12:13:01 AM Error Restore job failed Error: Failed to restore to GCE: [import-image]: 2023-09-20T17:09:43Z step "translate-disk" run error: step "wait-for-translator" run error: WaitForInstancesSignal FailureMatch found for "inst-translator-translate-translate-disk-xsst3": "TranslateFailed: error: inspect_vm: no operating systems found"

there's a lot of same VM with this error VM eg. some configuration and CentOS7, just this VM error, there's an anomaly with this VM
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0rjq.png)

anyone how to solved this problem,
thanks

i have try backup and restore  but failed

Answer (score 0):

GCE has specific requirements for a VM to be compatible. It is trying to translate the disk of the VM you had on VMware that was backed up, but failed. Be sure your boot disk is compatible and has the correct configuration - not all options work with the compute engine serial console: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/import/import-existing-image#prepare_boot_disk

Other things that could be an issue is if your boot disk consisted of multiple volumes, used LVM etc... https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/import/import-ovf-files#requirements